# How to return boolean statement if list has duplicates?

Tags: python

How would I code to return a `False` or `True` using `for` loops, etc. from list `l`?

Should I instead have a counter to count the duplicates?  I was thinking I could use the dot count notation to count how many duplicates their were. If it counted more than `2`, it would return `False`.

```
l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]

def allDifferent1D(l):
    for i in l:
        print(l.count(i))
        if l.count(i) > 1:
            return False
```

Right now this is returning:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Something to think about: @Martijn's answer is much faster than your approach. The list `count()` method has to check every element in the list each time you call it to count the number of elements - this means that for a 6 element list, you're checking the entire list 6 times, which should raise some red flags.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it's a simpler approach that doesn't require explicit loops - it uses the fact that by definition a set won't allow duplicates. If the list and the set have the same number of elements, it's because there were no duplicates to begin with:

```
def allDifferent1D(lst):
    return len(lst) == len(set(lst))
```

The above function will return `False` if there are duplicates in the `lst` list, and `True` if all the elements are unique, and doesn't require the input list to be sorted. For example:

```
allDifferent1D([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
=> False
allDifferent1D([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
=> True
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep a set of values seen, and return `False` as soon as see a duplicate:

```
def all_different(l):
    seen = set()
    for i in l:
        if i in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(i)
    return True
```

A simplification would be to just create the `set()` in one go and test for the lengths; a shorter set means there were duplicates. This does more work; for a large list the above approach is more efficient as it'll *short-circuit*; return `False` as soon as a duplicate is found.

Note that your counting approach scans the list *in its entirety each time*, you created a quadratic algorithm; the amount of work multiplies as you add elements to the list.

Comment: @freeforalltousez: yes; for a list of `n` elements, up to `n**2` tests are made as each `.count()` scans `n` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This approach would produce a solution with O(nlogn) comlexity and O(1) space.

When you sort a list, the duplicated values should be neighbors, without using a set to store items that we have already seen, we can use O(1)-space algorithm.

When we are sorting elements (assuming that Python use optimal sorting algorithms ) the complexity is`O(nlogn)`. We traverse the list, in the worst case we traverse all the list `O(n)`. So in this case, we have `O(nlogn)` complexity algorithm.

```
l = [1,2,2,3,4,4]

def isDup(l):
    l=sorted(l)
    index=0
    isFound=False
    while not isFound and index<len(l)-2:
        if l[index+1]==l[index]:
            isFound=True
        else:
            index+=1
    return isFound

print isDup(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

here the simple one:

```
 >>> def dup_check(l):
         return sorted(l) == sorted(set(l))

 >>> dup_check([1,2,3,8,1])
 False
 >>> dup_check([1,2,3,8,])
 True
```

`set` will remove duplication, if list has no duplicate, then sorted(l) == sorted(set(l)) will return `True` else `False`

Comment: A simpler version is checking for the length of the set: `return len(l) -- len(set(l))`. This is certainly much faster.